# How do I Insert Into the <head> from a template file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for a project, and I would like to customize the stylesheets that each page calls. I have a universal header and footer, being called in the controller like this:

```
$this->load->view("templates/header");
$this->load->view({page-to-load});
$this->load->view("template/footer");
```

As you probably can guess, the structure of the page is separated into three parts: the doctype along with the all the tags up to body, the body content itself, and lastly, the footer information along with the closing body and html tags.

I would like to insert a css resource into the header from the body content, so that I can leave the header as a generic file and just customize it from the content that is loaded, similar to how WordPress does it. However, I haven't found anything that can tell me how to accomplish this.

So my question is how do I customize what is in the header from the code in the body file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller, you can pass a variable to the view, like so:

```
$data['stylesheet'] = 'CustomPageStylesheet.css';

$this->load->view("templates/header", $data);
$this->load->view({page-to-load});
$this->load->view("template/footer");
```

Then, in your header view, you will have access to a variable `$stylesheet` which you can use to load a custom stylesheet for that particular controller.

Comment: I love it! Works great, and looks clean. Thanks!

Comment: This is documented in the CodeIgniter User Guide, so if you would like additional information and examples, please refer to [Adding Dynamic Data to the View](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)